# Conditional regex in powershell search and replace

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to search and replace in powershell multiple xml files recursively. I would like to avoid the script from replacing certain occourances of matching text.

For example if you take the below sample XML

```
<title>this is a web-site</title>
<subtitle>web-site experience</subtitle>
<path>c:/web-site/web-site.xml</path>
</doc>
```

should be changed as the below after the script

```
<title>this is a new-site</title>
<subtitle>new-site experience</subtitle>
<path>c:/web-site/web-site.xml</path>
</doc>
```

if you see the above i want to ignore the string /web-site/ and /web-site.

I'm trying to use a OR operator and ignore and replace with the below code but it does not seem to help.

```
$content -replace '(^|[^/])web-site([^/]|$)|(^|[^/])web-site([^.]|$)', '$1new-Site$2' |
        Out-File $file.FullName -Encoding utf8
```

Can you let me know how to use conditional OR for multiple conditions

Comment: You probably should select the xml node using e. g. xpath and then change the content?

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly. Since it's xml document - do you want to just ignore nodes other than title?

Comment: This is just a minor variation of your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's XML, I suggest to parse this files like XML. Take a look at following snippet:

```
$xml = [xml]"<doc>
<title>this is a web-site 1</title>
<title>this is a web-site 2</title>
<subtitle>web-site experience</subtitle>
<path>c:/web-site/web-site.xml</path>
</doc>"
$xml.doc.SelectNodes("title") | % { $_.InnerText = $_.InnerText.Replace("web-site", "new-site") }
$xml.doc.title
```

Comment: unfortunately I cannot use parsing with nodes as there are many different nodes where this can match. So instead I was looking for a regex like above